# Is it possible to create a top-level collections in Firestore with angularfire2?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Reading the [Angularfire GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) page on collections doesn't reveal much about my how to create a top-level collection.

Is it possible to create a top-level collection through the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are created automatically when you write a document to them. This applies equally to top-level collections or nested collections.

So if you follow the instructions in [adding documentation to a collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection), you'll be creating a collection.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! I'll give this a try ( including reading the docs more thoroughly ).